# iOS custom keyboard for multiple choice

Tags: iphone, keyboard

I am trying to make an update for my trivia app and want it so that when the user types in the answer he/she only has the option to click A,B,C, or D. Is this possible? and if so, would apple allow this and how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also just create a custom view with four buttons that appears when necessary. It would be easier than customizing the keyboard, and depending on how you design and implement it, it'll probably look better than an action sheet. [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) provides a rich set of methods to animate views with ease.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can customise the keyboard, all the documentation is in the developer library.  But it sounds to me you'd be better off using a `UIActionSheet` if all you are doing is picking from four options.

*Edit: For reference, have a look at [Custom Views for Data Input](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html) in Apple's Text Programming Guide for iOS.*